# Wordpress error 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: wordpress

I am working on add image with comment with comment attachement plugin..but I got error in **wp-comments-post.php**
This happens when uploading file is larger then 79kb ...[image]

Comment: Make sure that your plugin is compatible with latest version of Wordpress.

Comment: i know its works in local but not in live

Comment: Check on your `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` settings in php.ini on the live server.

Comment: here is a link http://www.nillowpages.com/?page_id=89754 of phpinfo

Comment: post_max_size and upload_max_filesize  are 64M

Comment: If the server is protected with ModSecurity it will throw 413 if `SecRequestBodyAccess` is On and `SecRequestBodyNoFilesLimit` is too low. However, if that is the case you might want to change the way files are uploaded, cf. [Manual: SecRequestBodyNoFilesLimit](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#secrequestbodynofileslimit)

Comment: @xebeche thanks for your help. But I have added image via ajax. And so comment posting is working fine.

Comment: @vrajesh ajax is what I meant, i.a..

Comment: @xebeche what i need is to upload image with comment. first i had try to upload image with comment with $_POST(form action). but it showed error (see screenshot in question). so second I have take hidden filed in comment form so after upload image via ajax, I just need to add attachment id in hidden field and submit comment form. that's it!

Comment: So it works? Anyway, I wanted to point out that your error can be a result of ModSecurity.

Comment: @xebeche, error could be result of Modsecurity. But I have change my way to do that task.:)